# Unwanted Page is Loaded

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework, single-page-application, browser-cache

**Project Overview:**

I have made a Web System by using Django+AngularJS.
The Web System is basically an Authentication Portal, User logs in and does the stuff etc.

**Problem Statement:**

The problem I am facing is that I have logged out my system successfully and closed the browser. Then I visit the Web Page after a week, when I opened the Link https://www.foo.xyz so normally Login Page should Appear but instead of that it directs me to the Home of the System, which is not normal.
And it keeps happening until and I cleared the Browser's Cache, Restarted the Browser and Reopened the link.
*(I used Chrome and Firefox and I am facing the issue in both of them.)*

**What I need:**

First, thing is that I don't why does this happen?
Second, how can I fix it permanently?

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know how you made your web system, I'm going to be assuming a few things here.

Your page keeps the authentication information in cache, so that's why the page goes to the home and doesn't once the cache is deleted. If you want this not to happen, you're gonna need to find some way to auto-remove the authentication from the cache after *x* amount of time.